# count aggregate in query select on laravel4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I have the select like this:

```
StoreProduct::where('user_id', Auth::user()->main_id)
            ->whereNotExists(function($query)
            {
                 $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                       ->from('store_products')
                       ->whereRaw('store_products.store_product_id = store_product.id');
            })
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($perPage)
```

In my database are 20K rows, and this select execute about 65 seconds.

Im using laravel debugbar. Queries dump 2 select:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `store_product` where `store_product`.`deleted_at` is null and `user_id` = '20' and not exists (select 1 from `store_products` where store_products.store_product_id = store_product.id)65.88s
select * from `store_product` where `store_product`.`deleted_at` is null and `user_id` = '20' and not exists (select 1 from `store_products` where store_products.store_product_id = store_product.id) order by `id` desc limit 24 offset 0
```

Why laravel do `select count(*) as aggregate`? How to optimizate this query?

Comment: I'm guessing it's executing due to the `->paginate()` call. I suggest you execute the query `explain extended select count(*) ....` to check why is the query taking so long. Do you have a index on the column `store_products.store_product_id` ?